# Shopify: How add new image

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

I'm desperate to add images to my Shopify theme. I would like to point out that this is a personalized theme and that these are not images produced.

I export my image to my **src/img/image.png** folder and use this command in my [.liquid](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/) (= HTML files):

```
{{'Image.png' | Asset_img_url: '250x250' | Img_tag: '', 'className'}}
```

But nothing is displayed. My project is well configured, I can easily edit HTML and CSS, create new layouts etc. But cannnot export images.

Someone would have any idea ? I have not found anything to help me with Shopify documentation.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do mean by export? Add you images into the "assets" folder in your theme.

Comment: Shopify doesn't support folders inside the assets folder. If you are adding this src/img folder structure in there it won't work. Like @HymnZ  mentioned add the image directly in the asset folder.

Answer (score 1):

Put the image in `src/assets`

The Shopify `asset_img_url` filter will not read from any other folder or directory.